# Display html forms using ajax

Tags: ajax, forms

I want to create an ajax based page, where i can call a form from another php file to display when user asks for it and also submit the form data through another ajax. The later process is familiar but i have some confusion regarding the former.How can i do it? can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying for this:

Consider this:

index.php(or other file where the form should be called):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script>
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "form.php?id="+Math.random(), true);
xmlhttp.send();
function later_process(){//form submission here(since you are familiar.I may also provide it just give a comment.}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

form.php

```
/* No body/head/!doctype declarations */
<form method="post">
</form>
```